# Displaying numbers between 0.1-1.9, 2.0-2.9 etc.,

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

As the title says I'm trying to display numbers between 0.1-1.9 as Season 1 then 2.0-2.9 season 2 etc., that's what I have tried so far

```
 $sql="SELECT Patch_No, Created FROM info ORDER BY Patch_NO DESC";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if(!isset($seasons[ceil($data['Patch_No'])])||is_int($data['Patch_No'])&&ceil($data['Patch_No'])==$data['Patch_No']+1){

                $seasons[ceil($data['Patch_No'])]=ceil($data['Patch_No']);
                echo '<hr><i>SEASON '.ceil($data['Patch_No']).'<br></i><hr>';

            }

            echo '<a href="delete_patch.php?Patch_No='.$data['Patch_No'].'" alt="'.$data['Created'].'" title="'.$data['Created'].'">
            '.$data['Patch_No'].'</a><br>';

        }
        echo '<hr><hr><a href="index.php">CMS</a>';
```

And here is the result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfnzN.png pretty close

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the season easily in SQL.  In MySQL, for instance, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT Patch_No, Created, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Patch_No, '.', 1) as Season
FROM info
ORDER BY Patch_NO DESC;
```

Other databases have similar functionality that can be used for this purpose.

Note that this is just extracting the first digit from `Patch_No`, which appears to be your intention.

This actually separates 0.1-0.9 from 1.0, which makes sense to me.  If you want those as a single season, you can use a `case` statement.

```
SELECT Patch_No, Created,
       (CASE WHEN Patch_No like '%0' THEN '1'
             ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Patch_No, '.', 1)
        END) as Season
FROM info
ORDER BY Patch_NO DESC;
```